# Python: How to extract addresses from a sentence/paragraph (non-Regex approach)?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, location, extract, addressbook

I was working on a project which needed me to extract addresses from a sentence.

For e.g. Input sentence: `Hi, Mr. Sam D. Richards lives here Shop No / 123, 3rd Floor, ABC Building, Behind CDE Mart, Aloha Road, 12345. If you need any help, call me on 12345678`

I am trying to extract just the address i.e. `Shop No / 123, 3rd Floor, ABC Building, Behind CDE Mart, Aloha Road, 12345`

What I have tried so far:

I tried [Pyap](https://github.com/vladimarius/pyap) which also works on Regex so it is not able to generalize it better for addresses of countries other than US/Canada/UK. I realized that we cannot use Regex as there is no pattern to the address or the sentences whatsoever. Also tried `locationtagger` which only manages to return the country or the city.

Is there any better way of doing it?

Comment: Is there no common pattern before or after the addresses?

Comment: Nope, none whatsoever :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no obvious pattern for regex, you can try an ML-based approach. There is a well known problem *named entity recognition* (NER), and it is typically solved as a sequence tagging problem: a model is trained to predict for each token (e.g. a word or a subword) whether it is a part of address or not.

You can look for a model that is already trained to extract addresses (e.g. here https://huggingface.co/models?search=address), or fine-tune a BERT-based model on your own dataset ([here](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/tasks/token_classification) is a recipe).

Answer (score 1):

Addresses have a well known structure. With a grammar parser it should be possible to parse them.
PyParsing has a feature of scanning that searches for pattern without parsing all the rest of the file. You can try this feature. I have an example for you, that detects three addresses in the example string.

```
#!/bin/python3

from pyparsing import *

GermanWord = Word("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÄÖÜ", alphas + "ß")
GermanWordComposition = GermanWord + (ZeroOrMore(Optional(Literal("-")) + GermanWord))
GermanName = GermanWordComposition
GermanStreet = GermanWordComposition
GermanHouseNumber = Word(nums) + Optional(Word(alphas, exact=1) + FollowedBy(White()))
GermanAddressSeparator = Literal(",") | Literal("in") 
GermanPostCode = Word(nums, exact=5)
GermanTown = GermanWordComposition

German_Address = GermanName + GermanAddressSeparator + GermanStreet + GermanHouseNumber \
    + GermanAddressSeparator + GermanPostCode + GermanTown


EnglishWord = Word("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", alphanums)
EnglishNumber = Word(nums)
EnglishComposition = OneOrMore(EnglishWord)
EnglishExtension = Word("-/", exact=1) + (EnglishComposition | EnglishNumber)
EnglishAddressSeparator = Literal(",")
EnglishFloor = (Literal("1st") | Literal("2nd") | Literal("3rd") | (Combine(EnglishNumber + Literal("th")))) + Literal("Floor")
EnglishWhere = EnglishComposition
EnglishStreet = EnglishComposition


EnglishAddress = EnglishComposition + Optional(EnglishExtension) \
    + EnglishAddressSeparator + Optional(EnglishFloor)           \
    + Optional(EnglishAddressSeparator + EnglishWhere)           \
    + Optional(EnglishAddressSeparator + EnglishWhere)           \
    + EnglishAddressSeparator + EnglishStreet + EnglishAddressSeparator + EnglishNumber

Address = EnglishAddress | German_Address


test_1 = "I am writing to Peter Meyer, Moritzstraße 22, 54543 Musterdorf a letter. But the letter arrived at \
Hubert Figge, Große Straße 14 in 45434 Berlin. In the letter was written: Hi, Mr. Sam D. Richards lives here \
Shop No / 123, 3rd Floor, ABC Building, Behind CDE Mart, Aloha Road, 12345. If you need any help, call       \
me on 12345678."

for i in Address.scanString(test_1):
  print(i)
```